# How to find the area of Transformation on a Set D

Tags: calculus, matrices, linear-transformations

i have question that i asked here before but i didn't get clear answer , its not a Spam but i cant understand this question and i need help thank you.

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the set $D = \{(x, y, z) \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1~\text{and}~z = 0\}$. Let $T :  \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(x, y, z) = (2x − y + z, x − y + 10z, 3x − 7y + 2z)$. Find the area of $T(D)$.

i know that the new area can be anything i dont know why should i use the coordinates (0,0,1) , (0,1,0) i know that they are on the circule but how could i find the area when i dont know the shape of it on R3

**The Questino is most likely about Vector Product / dot product**

Reference : Question taken from Technion institute of Technology

Course : Calculas 2t  for electrical Enginners.

**heres what i got after thinking a bit :**

the trasnformation gets only two points (1,0,0) , (0,1,0) Based on conditions from Set D .

thats all every other T(**point**) is a liner combination of the Image T(1,0,0)
T(0,1,0).

so its a plane of the two vectors and each combination of them will still be on the plane so the area is the plane given by these vectors

so we use cross product and we get the area .

is this true ?.

Comment: a vector product gives the area of the parallelogram i do know that but how do you know that the transformation CREATED a parallelogram and how could i use that fact to solve the question

Comment: Here's an idea: you can parametrise the boundary of $D$, which is the unit circle in the $z=0$ plane, by $\left(x,y,z\right) = \left(\cos\theta, \sin\theta, 0 \right)$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. Then you can use this to parametrise the boundary of $T\left(D\right)$, and so you can calculate the contour integral along the boundary of $T\left(D\right)$. Now, it's been a few years since I last studied multivariable analysis, but Stokes' theorem comes to mind. Hope that helps.

Comment: the thing is we have just started the semester so we dont know how to calculate double integral and stuff like that we started to learn about vectors and its proporties like dot product and vector product and planes and distance of a point from plane stuff like that .

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by 'area of $T(D)$'. Since the set $D$ is the outline of a circle, its image $T(D)$ is also a 1-dimensional manifold, which has no 'area' per se. Do you mean the 1-dimensional surface measure of $T(D)$ i.e. the length or maybe the surface measure of the image of the circle enclosed by $D$ under the transformation $T$?

Comment: i copied the question from a homework paper they didn't clearify how and we didn't learn anything beside vectors

Comment: it is a two dimensional manifold , we have 2 vectors (-1,-1,-7) and (2,1,3) which makes a plane i think thats the point to find the area  given by the vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a transformation is a vector function: $$T(x,y,y)=(2x-y+z)\vec i+(x-y+10z)\vec j+(3x-7y+2z)\vec k$$

Where, the bounds of integration are $z=0$ and $x^2+y^2=1$, given this one can use integration to integrate the function $T$ on $D$, and it will give you the area since if you notice $z=0$. Which means the Domain of integration is a disk or $0\leq r\leq 1, z=0$, and $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$. these will come handy later.

Let, $$x=cos(\theta), y=sin(\theta),z=0$$$$dx=-sin(\theta)d\theta,dy=cos(\theta)d\theta,dz=0$$

The integral, then becomes: $$\int\int_V2dxdy-2dzdx-17dydz$$

where V is the region given by the set $D$.

However, the integrands with the term $dz$ cancel out yielding:
$$\int\int_V2dxdy$$

After putting in the values the integral ends up yielding 0. Which is not hard to see, Since $sin(2x)$ is periodic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I presume there must $\leq$ sign instead of $=$ in the expression $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in the definition of $D$. Here you indeed don't need to use double integral. I'll give you an intuitive solution to this problem.

Consider first not circle but square, what would happen to its area after this transformation? The area of the square can be found by two vectors that form its sides $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ (e.g. using vector product $\|u \times v\|$), after applying transform these two vectors become $T(u), T(v) \in \mathbb{R}^3$. And the area is equal to
$$\|T(u) \times T(v)\| = \|u \times v\| \cdot |\det T| \quad \text{(prove this)}$$
Intuitively, the area of a circle can be formed by infinetely many small squares, and hence it's possible to sum up all the areas and get the result:
$$\text{Area}(D) \cdot |\det T|$$
Greetings from Technion!

Comment: the det T is 112 or 0 since z =0

Comment: if its not 0 we are calculating the volume right ?

Comment: Determinant of a linear tranform is a measure of shrinking, that is initial set is shrinked by it, no matter if it's a plane figure with some area or body with volume. And, indeed this problem is a bit more complex if you need a strict proof.

Comment: the area by the transformation is : pi * | det T | but the z components should be 0 because of the condition on the Set D so our matrix is :  ( -1 -1 -7)                                 ( 2  1  3 )